# IEEE 2006 citation language

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I need to change the language of my citations from english to german. For the bibliography itself I've done this already changing the field command to `{\BIBLIOGRAPHY \l 1031}`.

Now the citations should be changed too: e.g. [6, p. 7] should become [6, S. 7]. The Field code for this citation is `{\CITATION GON13 \p 7 \l 2055}` 2055 is the Locale Identifier (LCID) of German(Switzerland). The language of the citation source can be set without affecting this field. The field itself can't be modified "This modification is not allowed because the selection is locked."

Is there a way to modify the field or do I have to modify the IEEE style itself respectively get a modified one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by creating a modified copy of IEEE2006OfficeOnline.xsl (Program Files(x86)/Microsoft Office/Office14/Bibliography/Style). It's as easy as replacing p. with S. in lines 6382 and 8036.